# How can I avoid an "Unchecked overriding" warning when interface method's generic return is implemented with a concrete type in Java?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

This is an educational question that relates to a hobby project. Project Spring Boot MVC/REST app.

I would like to retain the flexibility to be able to create multiple implementations of Service and have list return a list of objects, depending on what the implementation requires.

I appreciate I could create some inheritance/implementation hierarchy to define the kinds of objects of which T could encompass. My problem with both of those answers is that some use cases for Service involve me needing to return Lists of Java Standard Lib types - types I would rather not inherit/extend/implement for my own custom classes, which I would prefer be kept as lean as possible.

```
import java.util.List;

interface Service {
    <T> List<T> list(String location, MyEnums.mediaType type );
}

class MyEnums {
    enum mediaType {
        IMAGE, VIDEO, AUDIO
    }
}

class LocalService implements Service {
    public List<MyConcreteClass> list(String location, MyEnums.mediaType type ) {
        List<MyConcreteClass> list = null;
        list.add(new MyConcreteClass(1, "foo", new byte[0]));
        return list;
    }
}

class MyConcreteClass implements Comparable<MyConcreteClass> {

    private final long id;
    private final String name;
    private final byte[] data;

    public MyConcreteClass(long id, String name, byte[] data) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.data = data;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyConcreteClass o) {
        return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
    }

    // Other methods omitted for brevity
}
```

The above code is only a simplified example of the actual app code - which compiles and runs without any (known) runtime bugs. However I get the compiler warning:

> Unchecked overriding: return type requires unchecked conversion.

The presence of a warning makes sense to me - code consuming the Service interface/API could break at runtime if the return type requirement in the calling code is incompatible with the implementation, whereas the error would be caught at compile if I had a more specific List<> defined in the interface.

This would, of course, not be an issue if I had to wire in a concrete implementation into the code consuming my service - however the joys of Spring!

**What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this? Are generics the right way to achieve a polymorphic list() function in my case?**

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The Service should be generic, not just the method. So `Service<T>`, and then it would either be `LocalService implements Service<MyConcreteClass>`. But I don't understand why you would want disparate services to all implement a common interface. Surely the CustomerService and the OrderService (or whatever) are not in any way interchangeable. By the way, class names are PascalCase by convention in Java.

Comment: @DavidConrad - thanks for your initial comments. Have edited code into something that will at least compile. Could you help me understand why **both** interface and one of its methods need to be generic? I may want many other methods in Service which are not generic/do not make use of <T> at all. As for why I want disparate services implementing a common interface - I have just realized that although not using a DB for this part of app - my actual need for multiple services comes down to multiple storage endpoints and I should probably leave multiple impl. for data layer.

Comment: With only the method in the interface being generic, not the interface itself, there is no way for the compiler to know if the return value of the method in the concrete class conforms to the interface. It doesn't matter if not all methods in the generic interface use the generic type, but putting the type on the interface and the class allows the compiler to see they are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eliminate the unchecked cast by declaring the interface itself with a type parameter (instead of the method). Like this:

```java
interface Service<T> {
    List<T> list(String location, String type );
}

class LocalService implements Service<MyConcreteClass> {
    @Override
    public List<MyConcreteClass> list(String location, String type ) {
        // Some logic to retrieve, alter and return a list
        return null;
    }
}

class StringService implements Service<String> {
    @Override
    public List<String> list(String location, String type) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}

class MyConcreteClass {
    /// ...
}
```

(I changed a couple of things to make it compile, not relevant to the answer).

Comment: Having changed interface Service to Service<T> and also annotated the relevant method with @Override, I now get a "Raw use of parameterized class 'Service'" warning attached to the code "LocalService implements Service {...}. If I change it to "LocalService implements Service<MyConcreteClass>" I end up with same warning I had to begin with - i.e. - "Unchecked Overriding"

Comment: What tool is giving you that warning? It doesn't make sense, there is no longer any ambiguity about the type being returned. I have no warnings with the code in my answer (I did have the unchecked warning with your original code).

Comment: I had added an errant <T> before List<T> (i.e. <T> List<T> list(...)) in Service {...}. With that removed - the warning is gone. Thanks for your help. i will mark as answered.